# Number of binary operations isomorphism with 4 elements

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, binary-operations

Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$. What is the number of binary operations $*$ defined on $A$, such that $(A,*)$ is a group isomorphism to $(\Bbb Z_4,+)$, and the order of $3$ is $2$ in this group ?

I tried solving this using Cayley Tables but I am not really sure how to count all of them. All I know is that the structures of the tables should be similar in an isomorphism.

Can you explain how to do this?

I struggle with group theory so I would appreciate more "elementary" answers or at least detailed.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to formulate mathematical formulas in your MSE questions. As for you question, $\Bbb{Z}_4$ has exactly one element of order $2$ and you are told to name that element $3$. How many ways are there for using the names $1$, $2$, and $4$ for the other $3$ elements?

Comment: @RobArthan I think $3!$ ways, right? But how can i be sure that each one of these permutations is going to be isomorphic ?

Comment: The permutation (along with $3 \mapsto 3$) gives you the isomorphism.